# Writing a backspace in a file

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream

```
int main(){
std::cout << "Insert file name / or path. \n NOTE: ONLY INPUTS. DELETES PREVIOUS DATA.\nV.6" << std::endl;
std::string filen;
std::cin >> filen;
std::ofstream myFile;
try{
myFile.open(filen, std::ios::out);
}
catch(std::fstream::failure){
std::cout << "Could not open file!\n Make sure the name and data type are valid.";
system("pause");
}
while(true){
    int press = getch();
    if(press == 43) myFile.close();
    if(press == 8){myFile << "\b" << " " << "\b";std::cout << "\b" << " " << "\b" << std::flush;}
    if(press == 13){ myFile << "\n"; std::cout << "\n" << std::flush;}
    if(press != 43 && press != 127 && press != 13 && press != 8){myFile << (char)press;std::cout << (char)press;}
       }
return 0;
}
```

Whenever I choose a text file and I press backspace, and I check the document and when I check the text document, I get random characters like so:

[image: Random Characters]

Comment: Off topic: You need to turn on exceptions for streams. By default streams don't throw. Generally better off without because input errors are way too common to be considered exceptional. You can test for success on a stream operation by testing the object `if (!myFile)` will enter the body of the `if`if the stream has reported an error. If you figure you want exceptions anyway, read this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @BoundaryImposition pointed out already, writing `"\b"` to your file, will actually write a binary backspace character to your file. What you probably want instead is `myFile.seekp(-1, std::ios_base::cur);`. If you are on win/dos machine you likely need extra care with `'\n'` characters because they are translated into `0x0d 0x0a` when written to a text stream (thus they require to seek back 2 positions instead of 1).

But generally, if you are not dealing with very huge files, it will be way easier to just store the content in a `std::string` (using `pop_back` or `erase`, to remove characters if needed) and write it to the file when you are finished.

Answer (score 5):

Those are not "random characters"; those are backspace characters! i.e. exactly the input you gave.

This can be verified with a hex editor (or piping the output of your program through `hexdump` et al).

If you wish to replicate the behaviour of common shells, you'll have to write your own code to identify the backspace character and, instead of appending it to `myFile`, instead eliminate the previously-entered character.

Comment: And this program is definitely not C!

Comment: How would that work? I am a nub to file I/O, for what I was told before was that the terminal takes characters differently from files.

Comment: Strange @user4581301 and, BoundaryImposition how am I to eliminate the last character?

Comment: @TheScripterGeek Boundary Imposition has answered this already: Watch for backspace and eliminate the previous character before writing it to the file. Once it is in the file getting it back out again is way more work than you want to do.

Comment: Well the project is that I don't have all of the characters stored in an array or something, I just have it already entered inside of the text document.

Comment: To be fair removing the previous character is a whole new can of beans. But I'm going to leave that for somebody else to explain as I am on holiday :)